# HAProxy how to redirect HTTP to HTTPS with fixed port and path

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, haproxy

my goal is to redirect all http call to https with fixed port and different alias.

for example,

> http://aaa.domain.com:7070 -> https://proxy.domain.com:443/aaa

> http://bbb.domain.com:7080 -> https://proxy.domain.com:443/bbb

in my current settings, I use redirect scheme for http to https

```
frontend http-in-aaa
bind :7070
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
```

```
backend https-proxy
balance roundrobin
server proxy proxy.domain.com:443
```

I am thinking to use a map (acl and -M flag) like this: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/configuration/acls/syntax/
for redirecting with path

but how do I also add the port number with map?